# <fb:login-button> not converted to the button in latest Firefox

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

I've been working with https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

Anyways, the output to the page in html shows fb:login-button but it doesnt get convereted to the actual facebook button in Firefox.  I have the facebook html tag, the fb init() at the bottom of my page.  It works in IE9 (haven't checked other browsers).

So why isn't it being converted by the fb javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its because I was logged in on facebook on FF, and not on IE.  The login button doesn't show if you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include the proper xml namespace in the `html` tag. Something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" lang="en">
```